# How to set a polygon over the region surrounding the Route at certain distance (in HereMaps)

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest, heremaps

I tried getting BoundingBox of route instance and set the polygon over it but the result was a rectangle over the route as shown in the image below which is inappropriate.

[image]

Also, I tried to add the BoundingBox of some color with alpha value for transparency over the geocoordinates in the route with a certain distance but the polygons were overlapping and hiding the visibility of Route, like in the image below. Note: (Red circle shows the route which is somewhat visible at certain location due to less overlapping)

[image]

I am unable to find any way using which I can merge the multiple polygons into one giant polygon surrounding the route like in 2nd image.

Below is my code which provided me the results in the 2nd image.

```
    fun addBoundingBoxTo(center: GeoCoordinate) {
        val boundingBox = GeoBoundingBox(center, 1000f, 1000f)
        val coordinates: MutableList<GeoCoordinate> = ArrayList()
        coordinates.add(boundingBox.topLeft)
        coordinates.add(GeoCoordinate(boundingBox.topLeft.latitude,
                boundingBox.bottomRight.longitude,
                boundingBox.topLeft.altitude))
        coordinates.add(boundingBox.bottomRight)
        coordinates.add(GeoCoordinate(boundingBox.bottomRight.latitude,
                boundingBox.topLeft.longitude, boundingBox.topLeft.altitude))
        val geoPolygon = GeoPolygon(coordinates)
        val polygon = MapPolygon(geoPolygon)
        polygon.fillColor = Color.parseColor("#77777777")
        polygon.lineWidth = 0
        map.addMapObject(polygon)
    }

    route.routeGeometry.forEach {
        addBoundingBoxTo(it)
    }
```

The desired result I want to achieve is like in the below image:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just create second polyline with the same coordinates as the Route polyline, but wider?

Comment: We want to show the polygon over the region which is some km/miles away. So, the polyline wouldn't work as it would parallel to route line

Comment: I see. 
Hmm, that should be also doable. You just get the waypoints of the polyline, move them in one direction, then move them also in the opposite direction, concatenate all those moved waypoints and use them to create new polygon.
I am not familiar with the SDK, but I could provide solution using Javascript API if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest December [release](https://www.here.com/learn/blog/december-2022-platform-release-notes), can now also specify up to 20 polygons in a routing request. This allows a more precise and simple way to define areas that should be avoided.